# PHPUnit Testing for JSON Output

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, phpunit

Why can't I get the input and test if it's not null?

My method I am testing:

```
/**
 * @method: getCategory
 * retrieves the categories
 * @return json category data
 */
public function getCategory() {

    $cat = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Category')->findAll();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($cat as $res) {
        $data[] = array(
            'catId' => $res->__get('catId'),
            'category' => $res->__get('category'),
            'item' => $res->__get('item')
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

My test:

```
 /**
 * @covers Category::getCategory
 * @todo   Implement testGetCategory().
 */
public function testGetCategory() {
    $json = $this->object->getCategory();
    $this->assertNotNull($json);
}
```

The error message, it returns a JSON array of objects:

> PHPUnit 3.7.8 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> `F[{"catId":1,"category":"FLORALS2","item":"RED ROSES"}, 
>   {"catId":2,"category":"TENTS","item":"12X14"}, 
>   {"catId":3,"category":"FLORAL","item":"WHITE ROSES"}, 
>   {"catId":4,"category":"TENTS","item":"15X24"}, 
>   {"catId":5,"category":"CHAIRS","item":"BLACK CHAIR"}, 
>   {"catId":6,"category":"CHAIRS","item":"RED CHAIRS"}, 
>   {"catId":7,"category":"TENTS","item":"23X23"}, 
>   {"catId":8,"category":"CANDLES","item":"RED CANDLES"}, 
>   {"catId":9,"category":"CANDLES","item":"WHITE CANDLES"}, 
>   {"catId":10,"category":"CANDLES","item":"BLACK CANDLES"}, 
>   {"catId":11,"category":"CANDLES","item":"ORANGE CANDLES"}, 
>   {"catId":12,"category":"TABLE","item":"4X8 TABLE"}, 
>   {"catId":13,"category":"DRAPERYS","item":"24\" WHITE LINEN"}, 
>   {"catId":14,"category":"LINEN","item":"WHITE CURTAINS"}, 
>   {"catId":17,"category":"DRAPERY","item":"SILK TABLE CLOTH"}, 
>   {"catId":18,"category":"FLORAL","item":"ORANGE DAISIES"}]..`
>
> Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 10.25Mb
>
> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) `CategoryTest::testGetCategory` Failed asserting that null is not
>   null.
>
> `/var/www/praiseDB/tests/controller/CategoryTest.php:42`

Comment: The assertXXXX is basically the reverse of what you are thinking.  For instance, the assertNotNull will throw the assert when the the text is Null. Your $json is NULL since it was echo'd, not returned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your getCategory() function echoes something out:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

But it doesn't return anything.
Therefore the $json variable will be null in your test.

You probably meant to return the value at the end of the function instead:

```
return json_encode($data);
```

To test output, you would need to use the expectOutputString() or expectOutputRegex() methods in your test. To test for non-empty output, I believe the following should do:

```
/**
 * @covers Category::getCategory
 * @todo   Implement testGetCategory().
 */
public function testGetCategory() {
    $this->expectOutputRegex('/./');
    $this->object->getCategory();
}
```

See the [phpunit documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.output) for details on how to assert output.

Comment: Yes, this is the way it's supposed to return. I have an ajax call that get the request. Apparently I am unable to test it this way, so how do I test that the method echoes something?

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is a controller method. Since this is return output I need to write a test to verify that the controller method is returning output but I cannot find any good examples or tutorials.

Comment: ok, so the echoing was indeed what you wanted, I edited my answer to add some details on how to assert output with phpunit

Comment: Had the same problem, cost me 4hrs to find out ... Thanks for the answer, saved my day :)